# How to Control Table Properties

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to correct table indentation using the following condition:
All tables in the document of `Tbl.Rows.LeftIndent = 0.74` should be updated to `Tbl.Rows.LeftIndent = 0.`

The code below generated the following error:

> "Object variable or With block variable not set."

```vb
Sub FixEmbeddedTableIndent()
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim blnFound As Boolean
    With ThisDocument.Range.Find
        tbl.Rows.LeftIndent = 0
        Do
            blnFound = .Execute
            If blnFound Then
                tbl.Rows.LeftIndent = 0.74
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Note: This condition is needed since there are two types of tables in the document, and the macro should update only one kind of table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the `Find` method to discover table row indents. And, in any case, you can't use the found object before making sure that you found something. If nothing was found there is no such object, of course.

The code below is a better approach.

```
Sub FixEmbeddedTableIndent()

    Dim Tbl As Table

    ' Using ThisDocument will require you to paste the code into
    ' every document in which you want to use it.
    ' The ActiveDocument could be one which doesn't have this code.

    With ActiveDocument
        For Each Tbl In .Tables
            With Tbl.Rows
                If .LeftIndent = InchesToPoints(0.74) Then
                    .LeftIndent = 0
                End If
            End With
        Next Tbl
    End With
End Sub
```

Note my use of the InchesToPoints() function. Word stores the indent in points. When you see the indent as 0.74 (inches?) that is an approximate conversion. Therefore InchesToPoints(.74) - which works out to 53.28 - may not be the value actually set. Therefore my code may not discover the tables you are after. You might want to allow a range of, say, 53 to 54 points or even larger.

You can allow more flexibility in specifying the table you wish to readjust by any of the following methods.

```
If .LeftIndent > 51 Then
If .LeftInden < 60 Then
If (.LeftIndent > 51) And (.LeftIndent < 60) Then
```

Comment: I added an answer to your question to my above solution.

Comment: If it worked, please mark the answer as "Selected". Thank you.